# React - Nested routes - Get depth of current URL

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a tree structure with a recursive component that uses react-router. Can we find the current depth of the current URL?

```
RootNode
--Child1
----SubChild1
----SubChild2
--Child2
----SubChild3
```

Here RootNode will be Level 1, Child1, Child2 will be level 2, etc...

```
function Node() {

    const { id } = useParams();
    const { url, path } = useRouteMatch();

    const { loading, data } = useApi(NODES);
    const { nodes } = data || {};

    return (
        <>
            <h2>Level 1</h2>
            {
                nodes?.map(x =>
                    <p key={x.id}>
                        <Link to={`${url}/${x.id}`}>
                            {x.name}
                        </Link>
                    </p>
                )
            }

            <Switch>
                <Route path={`${path}/:id`}>
                    <Node />
                </Route>
            </Switch>
        </>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass the depth variable into the next component.

```
function Node({depth = 0}) {

const { id } = useParams();
const { url, path } = useRouteMatch();

const { loading, data } = useApi(NODES);
const { nodes } = data || {};

return (
    <>
        <h2>Level 1</h2>
        {
            nodes?.map(x =>
                <p key={x.id}>
                    <Link to={`${url}/${x.id}`}>
                        {x.name}
                    </Link>
                </p>
            )
        }

        <Switch>
            <Route path={`${path}/:id`}>
                <Node depth={depth + 1}/>
            </Route>
        </Switch>
    </>
);
}
```